# NIntegrate: Catastrophic loss of precision

Tags: numerical-integration

Below is a simplified code that I am trying to evaluate. I am basically getting the rms value of a Wakefield function. When I finally try to evaluate the rms, I get an error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
sigmaS = 50*10^-6;

gaussian2[s_?NumericQ] := 1/(Sqrt[2 Pi] sigmaS) Exp[-(s^2/(2 sigmaS^2))]

fo2[s_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[gaussian2'[sprime]/(s - sprime)^(1/3), {sprime, -Infinity, s}]

rms2 = Sqrt[
  NIntegrate[
    gaussian2[x] (fo2[x])^2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] - (NIntegrate[
     gaussian2[x] fo2[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}])^2]
```

Comment: Please provide a *complete* and *working* (even if that means working to an error) example. As it is, your code is non-functional.

Comment: Whoops, that should do it. I was missing a constant!

Comment: How long does it take to spit out the error?

Answer (score 3):

The integral for `fo2` can be computed exactly, which makes the numerical computation of `rms` straightforward:

```
Clear[s, gaussian2, fo2];

sigmaS = 50*10^-6;

gaussian2[s_] := 1/(Sqrt[2 Pi] sigmaS) Exp[-(s^2/(2 sigmaS^2))];

fo2[s_] = Integrate[gaussian2'[sprime]/(s - sprime)^(1/3), {sprime, -Infinity, s}, 
  Assumptions -> s < 0];

rms2 = Sqrt[
  NIntegrate[gaussian2[x] (fo2[x])^2, {x, -Infinity, Infinity}] -
    (NIntegrate[gaussian2[x] fo2[x], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}])^2
   ]

(*
  77003.5
*)
```

Note: The integral for `fo2` evaluates to a `ConditionalExpression` with `Re[s] > 0`, if no assumptions are given or if the assumption that `s` is real is given.  However we get two results with either assumption that `s > 0` or `s < 0`, both of which are equivalent.  Hence the assumption `s < 0` above.

```
intpos = Integrate[
  gaussian2'[sprime]/(s - sprime)^(1/3), {sprime, -Infinity, s}, 
  Assumptions -> s > 0]
(*
  180000/7 10^(1/3) ((7 Gamma[2/3] Hypergeometric1F1[2/3, 1/2, -200000000 s^2])/
   Gamma[-(5/3)] - (
   7500 2^(1/6)
     s Gamma[13/3] Hypergeometric1F1[7/6, 3/2, -200000000 s^2])/
   Sqrt[π])
*)

intneg = Integrate[
  gaussian2'[sprime]/(s - sprime)^(1/3), {sprime, -Infinity, s}, 
  Assumptions -> s < 0]
(*
  (1/Sqrt[π])200000 5^(1/3) (Gamma[5/6] Hypergeometric1F1[2/3, 1/2, -200000000 s^2] - 
   10000 Sqrt[2]
     s Gamma[4/3] Hypergeometric1F1[7/6, 3/2, -200000000 s^2])
*)

intpos - intneg // FullSimplify
(*
  0
*)
```